# How to solve this wrong algorithm in DatePicker?

Tags: android, date, datepicker

Here's my problem, My system should generate a specific date whenever I'm picking a date in Date Picker. Here's the picture of Date Picker with Alert Dialog:

[image: screenshot1]

DatePicker:

[image: screenshot2]

The specific date should be +5 days according to your current date, For example. I'll borrow a book on January 27, 2018. I should return it before or equal to the date of February 1, 2018. But my problem is whenever I pick January 27, 2018, on Date Picker. The dates are messed up. What should I do?

Here's the code for my program:

```
public class Borrow extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference databaseBorrow;
private Button btnBorrow;
public TextView tvScheduleDate,tvSchedule,tvReturnDate;
private int day,month,year,hour,minute;
private int dayFinal,monthFinal,yearFinal,returnDay;
 // private Date date;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_borrow);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();



    String id = intent.getStringExtra(SearchFragment.BOOK_ID);
    final String bookTitle = intent.getStringExtra(SearchFragment.BOOK_TITLE);
    btnBorrow=(Button)findViewById(R.id.borrowBtn);
    databaseBorrow= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Borrow").child(id);


    btnBorrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         Button();
    }
});

}

private void Button(){

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.borrow_dialog,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout));


    tvScheduleDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvScheduleDate);
    tvReturnDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReturnDate);
    tvSchedule = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvSchedule);
    tvSchedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(Borrow.this , Borrow.this , year,month,day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,6); //for max date
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    dialogBuilder.setView(view);
    dialogBuilder.show();
    /*
    String ids = databaseBorrow.push().getKey();
    String buttonText = btnBorrow.getText().toString();
    BorrowBook borrow = new BorrowBook(ids,buttonText,bookTitle,yearFinal,dayFinal,monthFinal);
    databaseBorrow.child(ids).setValue(borrow);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Borrow Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        yearFinal = i;
        monthFinal = i1+1;
        dayFinal = i2;


    tvScheduleDate.setText(dayFinal+"-"+monthFinal+"-"+yearFinal);
    // I think I used a wrong algorithm for this one , any suggestions so I 
    can solve this? 
    if(dayFinal>=27) {
        dayFinal=((i2+5)*0+1);
            monthFinal=i1+2;
            tvReturnDate.setText(dayFinal  + "-" + monthFinal + "-" + yearFinal);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: 'Dates are messed up' , can you elaborate?

Comment: For example, I'll borrow an item on January 27, 2018. I should return it on February 1, 2018. It should +5 days on your current date. But my program generates February 32, 2018 @CowboyFarnz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public String getFutureDate(String dt){

    String future_date = "";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);  // number of days to add
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    future_date = sdf1.format(c.getTime());

    return  future_date;
}
```

Usage

```
String format_date = yearFinal + "-" + monthFinal  + "-" + dayFinal ;
tvReturnDate.setText(getFutureDate(format_date));
```

Comment: Here's my last question, Is it possible to store this generated date in a database? for example, I want to store it in firebase database?

Comment: yes ofcourse, define global String fut_date; then get it by fut_date = getFutureDate(format_date) and you can use anywhere within the Activity

Answer (score 0):

Global variable declaration into your activity class:

```
private Button mPickDate;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
```

write down this code into onCreate() function:

```
//date picker presentation
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);//button for showing date picker dialog 
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) { showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); }
    });

// get the current date
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


// display the current date
updateDisplay();
```

write down those function outside of onCreate() function:

```
//return date picker dialog
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}

//update month day year
private void updateDisplay() {
    mBodyText.setText(//this is the edit text where you want to show the selected date
        new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
        .append(mYear).append("-")
        .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
        .append(mDay).append(""));


            //.append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            //.append(mDay).append("-")
            //.append(mYear).append(" "));
}

// the call back received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
};
```